# Restful services - Unable to access pages (jsp) even after rest filter config

Tags: java, jsp, rest, resteasy

Using below web.xml (with out filter config) i can able to connect with rest services, but after this i couldn't access JSP pages under the servlet.so included a filter for rest easy inside web app tag, but after inserting filter that ear file failed to deploy in JBOSS, so am i handling the filter wrongly here.

```
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>RNO/routebean/no-interface</param-value>
</context-param>   

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>   

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>Resteasy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Resteasy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a jsp in a static way? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: @user2267921 Normal i look up my page as http://localhost:8080/mywar/index.jsp, but after made Resteasy as servlet i couldn't able to access the jsp page but able to access the resteasy method from url http://localhost:8080/mywar/myrest/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out solution with help of [RESTEasy Application](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial?showall=) ,but used the web.xml of mine as u see below. It work as i expected rest request hit the rest pojo and jsp requests are hitting the mapped servlet.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>  

<filter>
    <filter-name>Resteasy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>me.sample.HelloApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Resteasy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you map Resteasy servlet to `/*`, **you** are asking the container to give all URLs to the servlet. A common usage is to map the servlet to a restricted set of URLs like :

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myrest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(I used `myrest` since it is the example you provided in you comment)